# Ubuntu server version

Tags: web-hosting

does anyone know the "best" Ubuntu version to choose for a VPS host? i'm after stability and scalability. Slicehost offers Hardy, Intrepid, Jaunty and Kramic. any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Karmic is the latest version of Ubuntu released at the moment. Usually you would go for that.

If you wanted a distribution that's going to be stable and supported for longer, you would go for a Long Term Support ([LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS)) release. The last LTS release was Hardy, but it's quite old now; the next LTS, Lucid, is coming out to replace it this month.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a production system, stick with the [LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS) releases. The current is 8.04, but 10.04 will be out at the end of April.